# Filter large resultset on calculated field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a search procedure that needs to return results using a specific price type.  This price type, depending on the customer who has granted the searcher access, is a calculated price.  We use a UDF to calculate this price.  So depending on the search submitted it can be many different possible prices coming back.  In addition to the price type being searched we also need to filter the results by a FROM and TO price and then a Sales Margin range.

This is simplified but basically the search will look something like this...

```
SELECT Name, Model, f_GetPrices(modelID, @userID, priceType)
FROM products
WHERE  f_GetPrices(modelID, @userID priceType) Between @from and @to
     AND (RetailPrice-f_GetPrices(modelID, @userID, priceType) / Retail Price * 100) Between @fromMargin and @toMargin
```

The problem is that I'm calling this UDF 4 times per record.

This is a simplified version, normally I insert all my results into a Temporary Table.  then I pull just the page I want using @pageSize and @pageNumber and in a second results I return back the total rows returned.  This allows our UI to do paging and show total number of records.

I've considered dumping the calculated price into the temporary table and then doing my WHERE clause in the SELECT that pulls from there.  However, since I am already doing that for paging I would actually need to dump into a temporary table all records with calculated price, then pull just the ones that are in the price ranges, then pull a final time for paging and total records, so two temporary tables of results.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this.

If I call the UDF 4 times in the select, does the SQL engine run that 4 times or does it just calculate it once and use that results in all 4 places per record?

If I select 10,000 records and only 100 of them would meet the price criteria (From, To, FromMargin, ToMargin) it seems like such a waste to persist those 10k records just to grab 100.  That why I was trying to apply the price ranges to the initial select.  But then I thought that SQL would need to do the calculations on all 10k records anyway to apply the WHERE clause.  Is it the same load to calculate price ranges on the fly as it would be to calculate, dump into a temp table, and then select again off that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a subquery:

```
select *
from (SELECT Name, Model, f_GetPrices(modelID, @userID, priceType) as fgp
      FROM products
     ) p
WHERE fgp Between @from and @to and
      (RetailPrice-fgp) / RetailPrice * 100) Between @fromMargin and @toMargin;
```

I also slightly modified the logic on the last condition, so the difference is divided by the `RetailPrice`.

Comment: It's not showing in my simplified version but I'm already putting the entire result call into a subquery so that I can then select out of it for paging.   So I would just go one level deeper, do I start running into performance issues if I subquery too far?

Comment: @IshmaelStruan . . . SQL Server does a good job optimizing subqueries.  I wouldn't worry about an additional level.  For readability reasons, you could use a CTE (the `with` statement); these are essentially equivalent to subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are optimizing for performance here, try to rewrite `f_GetPrices()` to be an inline table-valued function instead of a scalar function.  Scalar functions are usually [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/).

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions

http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/

Your modified query will look something like this:

```
  SELECT
    Name, Model, Price
  FROM products
  CROSS APPLY tvf_GetPrices(modelID, @userID, priceType) f
  WHERE Price Between @from and @to
    AND (RetailPrice - Price) / Retail Price * 100 Between @fromMargin and @toMargin
```

Your function definition will look something like this:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_GetPrices](
    @modelId   int,
    @userID    int,
    @priceType int
  )
  RETURNS TABLE
  RETURN (
    SELECT foo AS Price
    FROM bar
    WHERE @modelId
    etc
  )
```

Comment: After reading through the articles this is making sense (although why it is this way is a bit confounding).  I'm going to try this out now.  Why do I use CROSS APPLY in this example instead of an INNER JOIN.  I get somewhat confused in the application of CROSS APPLY?

Comment: Unfortunately this is SQL2k and I don't think CROSS APPLY works.  Getting errors trying to do this with inner join.